# Node js object exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

Got a pretty simple question to which I cant find an answer regarding exporting a object form a module in Node js, more specifically accessing the objects properties.

Here is my object I export:

```
exports.caravan = {
    month: "july"
};
```

And here is my main module:

```
var caravan = require("./caravan")

console.log(caravan.month);
console.log(caravan.caravan.month);
```

Why cant I access the properties directly with caravan.month but have to write caravan.caravan.month?

Comment: *"If it were caravan be a function, I could simply call it with caravan()"* – no you couldn't.

Comment: @Juhana You're right, I could not, it would be caravan.caravan().

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Consider that with `require`, you gain access to the `module.exports` object of a module (which is aliased to `exports`, but there are some subtleties to using `exports` that make using `module.exports` a better choice).

Taking your code:

```
exports.caravan = { month: "july" };
```

Which is similar to this:

```
module.exports.caravan = { month: "july" };
```

Which is similar to this:

```
module.exports = {
  caravan : { month: "july" }
};
```

If we similarly "translate" the `require`, by substituting it with the contents of `module.exports`, your code becomes this:

```
var caravan = {
  caravan : { month: "july" }
};
```

Which explains why you need to use `caravan.caravan.month`.

If you want to remove the extra level of indirection, you can use this in your module:

```
module.exports = {
  month: "july"
};
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to get via `caravan.month` then:

```
module.exports = {
    month: "july"
};
```

Comment: Try `module.exports = { /* ... */ }`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the object, use

```
module.exports = {
  caravan = {
       month: "july"
  }
};
```

and then get it like this:

```
var caravan = require("./caravan")
```

You may also check:

```
console.log(caravan.caravan.month);
```