# What am I doing wrong in my module export from main.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module-export

Learning how to develop modules I'm trying to learn how to export one from *main.js*. On my **renderer** I can send it correctly to **main** with:

*renderer.js:*

```
let _object = {
    foo: foo1,
    bar: bar1,
}
ipcRenderer.send('channel', _object)
```

in *main.js* I can get this correctly:

```
ipcMain.on('channel', (e, res) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
  console.log(typeof res)
})
```

however when I export the `result` from *main.js* and try to bring it into another file I get an `undefined`:

*main.js:*

```
const foobar = require('./foobar')

ipcMain.on('channel', (e, res) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
  console.log(typeof res)

  module.exports.res = res
  foobar.testing()
})
```

*foobar.js:*

```
const res = require('./main')

module.exports = {
    testing: function(res) {
        console.log(`Attempting console.log test: ${res}`)
        console.log(res)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
    }
}
```

terminal result:

```
Attempting console.log test: undefined 
undefined
undefined
```

I've also tried to redefine the object in *main.js*:

```
ipcMain.on('channel', (e, res) => {
  module.exports =  {
        foo: foo,
        bar: bar,
    }
  console.log(`Testing object ${res.foo}`)

  foobar.testing()
})
```

My research of reference:

- [Node js object exports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38283777/node-js-object-exports)
- [Node module.exports returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504541/node-module-exports-returns-undefined)

What a I doing wrong in my export of the `result` in *main.js* so I can use it in a different file?

### Edit:

My end goal is to learn how to be able to call `res.foo` in *foobar.js*.

Comment: Well first of all, you're printing `res` from arguments, which is undefined and shadows the imported variable.

Comment: So what is the proper way to restructure that in *main.js*?

Comment: Best way would be to just pass `res` as an argument to `testing` instead of using exports, but if you specifically want to use exports you'd just need to remove the argument from `testing` declaration. However I don't think that would help, because the `require` statement would snapshot the initial export, so you'd have to export an empty object and put the `res` in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have an argument `res` in your `testing` function, which shadows the import. Second, the imported `res` object is all exports from `main`, which includes the `res` you need - so you should print `res.res` instead of the whole object.

Foobar.js:

```
const res = require('./main')

module.exports = {
    testing: function() {
        console.log(`Attempting console.log test: ${res.res}`)
        console.log(res.res)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(res.res))
    }
}
```

The last version (where you reassign `module.exports`) would not work, because `foobar` will still have the original exports, which was an empty object.

Comment: So what is the proper rewrite in *main.js* so that I can just call `res.foo` in *foobar.js*?

Comment: Are you not allowed to change `foobar`? Then just do `foobar.testing(res)`, because your exports don't do anything the way it is written currently.

Comment: Feel free to make any better suggestions but please explain why, still learning this.